# Use an array as $cat1 in cat_is_ancestor_of

Tags: arrays, wordpress, categories

My category.php uses wp_list_categories to display the subcategories for certain categories, and also display the sibling categories for those subcategories. The particular subcategories is defined in the following string:

```
if ($this_category && ((cat_is_ancestor_of(258, $cat) or is_category(258)) || (cat_is_ancestor_of(252, $cat) or is_category(252)) || (cat_is_ancestor_of(238, $cat) or is_category(238)) ) ) { ?>
```

I'd like to replace this with an array for easier maintenance as the relevant categories change. I've written the following:

```
<?php $subCat = array(258, 252, 238);?>
if ($this_category && (cat_is_ancestor_of($subCat, $cat) or is_category($subCat) ) ) { ?>
```

This is working on the parent category pages, but not the subcategory pages. On the subcategories, the siblings are not displaying.

Can cat_is_ancestor_of use an array for the first variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through your array. Try this:

```
<?php 
$subCat = array(258, 252, 238);
$sub_str    = array();
foreach($subCat as $sub){
$sub_str[]    = '(cat_is_ancestor_of($sub, $cat) or is_category($sub))';
}
$qry    = implode($sub_str,'||');
if ($this_category && ($qry) ) { 
// do something
}
?>
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. One note though - I think you need to pull the variables out of the string in the $sub_str[] definition and concatenate them with the surround text so that they actually behave like variables, eg

$sub_str[]    = '(cat_is_ancestor_of(' . $sub . ', ' . $cat . ') or is_category(' . $sub . '))';

Comment: Hope I helped you a little :)